Clarification of Motor Velocity Constant Kv and Back EMF constant Ke
In the wiki link,
Motor Velocity constant is given as:

Is 'Vpeak' the peak Phase to Phase voltage OR the peak Phase to Neutral voltage?
 OR 
In the same wiki link they give an example:

Here the unit of Kv is RPM/V, again the 'V' in the denominator is the peak voltage between two phases?
In the same wiki, the Back EMF constant is mentioned in Volts/KiloRPM.
Looking at a few motor data sheets, I see that generally given in Vp/kRPM. In this context this is still Phase to Phase peak voltage?
I think they are Phase to Phase peak voltages, because generally the midpoint(neutral) is not brought out. Could you kindly confirm my assumption.

Data Sheet Link

Data Sheet Link

@Velvet Thanks, I have edited my question to reflect all the sources
